# finding geometric multiplicity of a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let

$A =\begin{bmatrix} a & 2f & 0 \\ 2f & b & 3f \\ 0 & 3f & c \end{bmatrix},  \tag 1$

where $a, b, c, f$ are real numbers and $f \ne 0$. What is the geometric multiplicity of the largest eigenvalue of $A$?

For a symmetric matrix the geometric multiplicity equals algebraic multiplicity,so we can check the eigen values of the matrix but I find that difficult to solve. Is there any different approach to this problem ? Can anyone give some idea. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited your post to $\LaTeX$ify it properly.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If we can show that the matrix has distinct eigenvalues then, we can say that the geometric multiplicity of the largest eigen value is 1.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $\lambda$ has the geometric multiplicity of $n,$ then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a-\lambda & 2f & 0 \\
2f & b-\lambda & 3f \\
0 & 3f & c-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has the rank $3-n.$

A rank of $1$ means that each row (or each column) is a multiple of the same vector.

A rank of $0$ means that the matrix is the zero-matrix.

Can any of these happen?

Answer (score 0):

As you claimed, the matrix is symmetric hence diagonalizable, and thus is the geometric multiplicity of any eigenvalue equal to its algebraic multiplicity.

If all $a,b,c,f$ are positive, by *Perron-Frobenius* theorem is the eigenvalue with the largest absolute value real and positive, and is simple (multiplicity 1). In other words, the spectral radius of the matrix is also an eigenvalue.